# CodeMirror electricInput does not match expression with leading whitespace

Tags: regex, codemirror

In my custom mode for CodeMirror, I want the electricInput event to fire when the user types a line starting with the word `bank` (with optional leading whitespace).

I have electricInput set up like this: `electricInput: /\s*bank$/i`

The event DOES fire when the user types `bank` at the beginning of a line. It does NOT fire when there are spaces before the word `bank`. Why?

(the RegEx seems to be fine. I have a grammar rule in that mode with the same RegEx, and it matches the token as expected, regardless of leading white spaces:

```
CodeMirror.defineSimpleMode("myMode", {
  start: [
    {regex: /\s*bank$/i, token: 'bank', sol: true, indent: true}
```

Comment: Looking at CoreMirror's source code, the regex does match, however CodeMirror performs a smart indentation afterwards and only triggers the event if the indentation changed. If it's like that, how can I get notified when the user types `bank` with leading whitespace? I would like to remove all indentation, not only newly created indentation but any indentation on such lines.

Comment: Set up your mode's indent function to return 0 for lines that start with `bank`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Marijn's kind help on the CodeMirror discussions forum, I was able to solve this: a custom `indent` function needs to be passed to `defineSimpleMode`. Then, we still need to set `electricInput` (because otherwise the indent function does not get called when typing `bank`). But no event handler for `onElectricInput` is required.

```
CodeMirror.defineSimpleMode("myMode", {
  start: [
    ...
  ],
  meta: {
    electricInput: /\s*bank$/i,
    indent: function (state, textAfter, line) {
      if (textAfter.substring(0, 4).toLowerCase() === 'bank') return 0
      return 2;
    }
  }  
});
```